Github Repo ADO Build Pipeline incorrectly running with Path filters
I have a github repo with format:
|
-| dirA
-| dirB
--| subDirA
-| dirC
fileA
fileB

In my azure pipeline yml, I have:
pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - develop
      - release/*
  paths:
    include:
      - dirA/**

I am trying to figure why when there is a PR containing changes only to dirB/subDirA that it is running the pipeline.  I have seen ADO return "skipped" back to github on occasion, but more often than not it will run the build.
Should I be using the "trigger" directive instead of the "pr" directive?

I have tested based on your YAML definition, it seems that the pipeline is triggered by CI instead of PR when you commit in dirB/subDirA folder.

If you do not enable the Disable implied YAML CI trigger from the Project Settings -> Pipeline Settings, then the CI trigger is enabled by default and any update in any path under any branch will trigger the pipeline. See the details from GitHub CI triggers.
Based on the current situation, it's suggested that you disable the CI trigger as shown below and try again.
trigger:
- none
pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - develop
      - release/*
  paths:
    include:
      - dirA/**

